# USB wifi adapter Belkin re-activate!

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I have a problem with my usb wifi adapter.

I have a dual boot computer with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and Windows 8.1. My usb wifi adapter is Belkin F7D1101 [Realtek RTL8188SU].

It used to work perfectly until yesterday, every time I was on Ubuntu!! Sometimes that was not working, i used to re-place the usb and everything was ok.

Also, in the windows system it still works.

On the Ubuntu system,  the command `lsusb`, shows the device plugged in. But the `ifconfig` shows only the Ethernet. I tried this [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1522815&highlight=Belkin%20F7D1101) but not worked.

It is very strange! Could someone give me an advice, please?

_______________ Update _______________

During the last time I used Ubuntu, those unattended-upgrades have happened:

> Start-Date: 2017-01-15  17:18:58
>   Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
>   Install: linux-signed-image-4.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-59.80, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-59.80, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-59.80, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-59:amd64 (4.4.0-59.80, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-59.80, automatic)
>   Upgrade: libdns-export162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.57.60, 4.4.0.59.62), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-57.78, 4.4.0-59.80), libvncclient1:amd64 (0.9.10+dfsg-3build1, 0.9.10+dfsg-3ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.57.60, 4.4.0.59.62), bind9-host:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.57.60, 4.4.0.59.62), dnsutils:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (24.0.0.186ubuntu0.16.04.1, 24.0.0.194ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.57.60, 4.4.0.59.62), libisc-export160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.12.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.14.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.12.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.14.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.3, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.12.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.14.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), linux-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.57.60, 4.4.0.59.62), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 (2.12.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.14.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.12.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 2.14.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
>   End-Date: 2017-01-15  17:21:17

Comment: A forum thread from 7 years ago is unlikely to be relevant. What happened yesterday, have you noticed an update, have installed sofware, have you changed any settings, etc.? Try to remember and update your question.

Comment: Realtek RTL8188SU is well supported since a few releases already and even if its driver had been updated, the new version can have issues, even regressions, but stop loading altogether is highly unusual so *something* must have happened.

Comment: Thanks for both answers! No new software installed but unattended-upgrades have happened indeed. I will edit the post and write them.

Comment: There's a kernel update. Try booting an older kernel just to see what happens.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem, thank you very much!